# Broken Image in Laravel

Tags: laravel-7

I'm working in the Laravel web-app. My images are stored in "public/assets/dist/img"

What I'm using in my view is :

```
<img src="{{asset('dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg')}}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 mr-3 img-circle">
```

but when I try to execute my Laravel app using "php artisan serve" I see my images are broken, when I try to inspect and get image src that is: **http://127.0.0.1:8000/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg**

It shows 404 | Not Found page.

I double checked that image with name "user1-128x128.jpg" exists in "public/assets/dist/img"

Why I'm not able to see the image?
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg` reachable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be :

```
{{ asset('/assets/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg') }}
```

assuming that your `/assets/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg` is under `/public/`

Comment: same issue, broken image

Comment: Can you see, if you hit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg`?

Comment: Happy to see my broken images working fine, this all because of you. Thank you